# Have problems setting up procfile when deploying a rails+react app on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, heroku, deployment, web-deployment

I am very new to deploy and have problems when I try to deploy a rails+react app on Heroku. **The first question is, should I deploy it separately? Or is there a way to deploy all of them together?** Because when I try to deploy both in one time, I got an error

```
No default language could be detected for this app.
remote: HINT: This occurs when Heroku cannot detect the buildpack to use for this application automatically.
```

So I guess it is because there are rails + react so it doesn't know which language to use?

Plus, here is how the structure of the app looks like:

```
api-backend
    --rails app
frontend
    --react app
Procfile.dev
package.json
...
```

My `procfile.dev` looks like:

```
web: PORT=3000 npm start
api: PORT=3001 bundle exec rails s
```

To deploy it in one time, I also tried to create a `package.json` file in the root by running `npm init`, it looks like:

```
{
  "name": "app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "## Introduction",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {


//should I put "start" here? What is supposed to be the command??
=================================================================

    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
```

To be honest, I don't know what is the right way to set these up, I check some tutorials but don't get it. Anyone has a recommendation to learn Heroku comprehensively?

Comment: Heroku only detects apps in the root directory, and you can only run one app per dyno. In production, the simplest thing is likely to get the Rails app to serve the outputs of the React app's build, then you only have a single app running and don't need to manage CORS, service discovery, etc.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Thanks! But I don't get it, how do I "get the Rails to serve the outputs of the React app's build"? So you mean, to deploy Rails app and the React app separately to Heroku?

Comment: No, that's exactly the *opposite* of what I mean. Build the React app, and configure the Rails app to serve the resulting assets *alongside the API*. Deploying them to two separate dynos would also work, but requires more configuration.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Oh ok thanks for explaining. I did build both apps already so they can talk to each other when in local. But would you mind explaining more about what I should do to deploy both of them and make them communicate together?